# Understanding effects in glmer by model specification

Tags: r, lme4

I'm trying to use the `glmer` function of the `lme4` package in `R` to run the following model on my dataset:

```
Approach ~ Group * Response * Stim.Type + Liking.Z + Age.Z + Context * Response + (1 | Subject)
```

`Approach` is a binary outcome (0 or 1). `Stim.Type`, `Response` and `Group` also have two levels. `Context` has three. `Liking.Z` and `Age.Z` are scalars.

I've noticed that the results change depending on the which level of an explanatory factor I set as the baseline. For example, `Stim.Type` has 2 levels: Food and Toy.

If I set toy as the baseline, the result is:

```
Fixed effects:
                                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                         4.05414    0.20486  19.790  < 2e-16 ***
GroupBN                            -0.18099    0.22321  -0.811 0.417452    
ResponseNogo                       -5.43113    0.19603 -27.706  < 2e-16 ***
Stim.TypeFood                      -0.37833    0.20156  -1.877 0.060524 .  
Liking.Z                            0.01095    0.03384   0.324 0.746277    
Age.Z                               0.11421    0.07117   1.605 0.108571    
ContextNegative                     0.04256    0.14357   0.296 0.766890    
ContextPositive                    -0.09674    0.13877  -0.697 0.485729    
GroupBN:ResponseNogo                0.25803    0.20319   1.270 0.204117    
GroupBN:Stim.TypeFood               0.56902    0.24398   2.332 0.019689 *  
ResponseNogo:Stim.TypeFood          0.80007    0.22715   3.522 0.000428 ***
ResponseNogo:ContextNegative       -0.01536    0.16300  -0.094 0.924908    
ResponseNogo:ContextPositive        0.10522    0.15920   0.661 0.508633    
GroupBN:ResponseNogo:Stim.TypeFood -0.21836    0.27975  -0.781 0.435073
```

If I set food to baseline I get:

```
Fixed effects:
                                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                        3.67496    0.19559  18.789  < 2e-16 ***
GroupBN                            0.38862    0.22293   1.743 0.081290 .  
ResponseNogo                      -4.63047    0.18366 -25.212  < 2e-16 ***
Stim.TypeToy                       0.37880    0.20189   1.876 0.060621 .  
Liking.Z                           0.01092    0.03385   0.323 0.746933    
Age.Z                              0.11431    0.07120   1.606 0.108367    
ContextNegative                    0.04287    0.14366   0.298 0.765360    
ContextPositive                   -0.09655    0.13886  -0.695 0.486872    
GroupBN:ResponseNogo               0.03941    0.19967   0.197 0.843532    
GroupBN:Stim.TypeToy              -0.56957    0.24433  -2.331 0.019744 *  
ResponseNogo:Stim.TypeToy         -0.80069    0.22755  -3.519 0.000434 ***
ResponseNogo:ContextNegative      -0.01578    0.16312  -0.097 0.922916    
ResponseNogo:ContextPositive       0.10498    0.15930   0.659 0.509905    
GroupBN:ResponseNogo:Stim.TypeToy  0.21898    0.28018   0.782 0.434471
```

For some of the interaction effects like `GroupBN:Stim.TypeFood` or `ResponseNogo:Stim.TypeFood` The effects are nearly (but not exactly) identical but reversed in sign as I would expect. But for some effects, espeically main effects that are specified as interactions in the model like `GroupBN` and `ResponseNogo`, The results are quite different.

I'm wondering why the results would change based on the way I specify the levels of factors in my model? Is the main effect for something like GroupBN being calculated only within the base level of the other factors (not what I thought), or across categories controlling for variance attributable to category differences (what I thought)? How can I specify my model best to be sure the effects I'm seeing are true here?

Thank!

Comment: Can you please include your formula call in your write up? It will help with explaining this... Essentially what is going on is that when you change your reference case, you are changing your model "intercept" (ie the predicted value of your outcome **Y** conditional on all **X** variables being equal to 0. `E(Y|X=0)`. But this is easier to explain concretely if you give the added detail

Comment: Also, this should probably be migrated to statsexchange since it's a statistical and not a programming question.